# How to talk to a Netty + Protobuf Server from .net client?

Tags: .net, client, protocol-buffers, netty

I have developed a Netty Server and it's also very easy to develop a Java client by following netty's sample projects via pure socket channel + Protobuf binary protocol.

But I can't get a reference project or sample code to access such a Netty server via .net client.

Could anyone provide such an example or reference document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use one of the existing .NET libs like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) or [protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/).

Comment: I'll try. But this libs cover the protobuf only. I'm not sure whether it will work under netty+protobuf. Anyway, thanks.